# Android screen Loanding

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, loading

I want to know that is th best way to create a loading screen , when a traitement works in background... like the white screen with loadingDialog in FaceBook app.
i though about a seperate activity like splashscreen but i d'ont think that is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's loading page is simply an `Activity` with an [animated GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif), while they spin off a background [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: i d'ont think so : i mean animated gif are not supported by all version

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask,

Instead of ProgressDialog You can use ProgressBar also

### ProgressBar with small Spinning Circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FIL_Main_RelativeLayout"
    android:background="@color/White">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
        android:id="@+id/FIL_Middle_ProgressBar"></ProgressBar>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

### For ProgressDialog

See my response in [show progressbar on button click when going from 1 intent to other and data is coming from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172409/show-progressbar-on-button-click-when-going-from-1-intent-to-other-and-data-is-co/6172564#6172564)

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but it is exactely what i did , i just want to make it look nicer : i mean changing the classic ugly ^^ progressdialog by a white layout (for example) and a small circle spining and some text. how can i do this : i tried to use layout visibility (GONE,VISIBLE...) but il doesn't work correctly.

Comment: See my updated response. I feel you want to use ProgressBar instead of ProgressDialog