# How to set progress bar in android?

Tags: android

I want set progress bar until the  next activity start.That mean i want to remove black screen while loading next page or activity.How to solve this problem?

yes I'm using button onClick and using listView to move next activity.

Comment: on click of button you are moving to next activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button b1 = new Button(this);
b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
            {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                     if(action==0)
                     {
                     }
                     else  if(action == 1)
                     {   
                        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(myFirstActivity.this,"Please wait","Loading...",true);
                         new Thread() 
                         {
                               public void run() 
                               {
                                    try 
                                    {
                                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                                    {
                                        e.toString();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    finally
                                    {
                                        dialog.dismiss();           
                                    }
                               }
                         }.start();
                      } 
                    return false;
                }
            });



     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                             Intent i1 = new Intent(myFirstActiviyt.this,Second.class);
                             startActivity(i1);
                             }
                             });
```

Try this

Comment: ah Sumant i need one more help how to use horizontal progress bar instead of this

Comment: just go to http://www.androidpeople.com/android-progress-dialog-style    http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html          http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html you will get info @ horizontal progress bar

Comment: Hello Sumant i have one problem. In spinner progress dialog that spinner not rotating

Answer (score 0):

try answer on this link

[show progressbar on button click when going from 1 intent to other and data is coming from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172409/show-progressbar-on-button-click-when-going-from-1-intent-to-other-and-data-is-co/6172464#6172464)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a progress bar using XML

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="55"
        android:progressTint="#02C697"/>
```